# getting private values in object

Tags: php

I have this data generate, but how do I get the values for the data such as the

User ID -> [id] => 1429517

message -> [data:ProtocolNode:private] => get my message

```
Array
(
[0] => ProtocolNode Object
    (
        [tag:ProtocolNode:private] => message
        [attributeHash:ProtocolNode:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1429517
                [offline] => 0
                [type] => text
                [t] => 14722889
            )

        [children:ProtocolNode:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => ProtocolNode Object
                    (
                        [tag:ProtocolNode:private] => body
                        [attributeHash:ProtocolNode:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [children:ProtocolNode:private] => 
                        [data:ProtocolNode:private] => get my message
                    )

            )

        [data:ProtocolNode:private] => 
    )

)
```

I have tried using this:

```
    foreach($msgs as $msg) {
    echo 'test: ' . $msg->tag ; 
    }
```

but I get the error:

Fatal error: Cannot access private property ProtocolNode::$tag

Comment: The class would need to offer a getter method to get these values. You could add that yourself if it doesn't but most likely the documentation will tell you how to get it.

Comment: You can only access private properties from within the instantiated class. To access such properties from the global scope you have to change property type to public or use a getter method that would return the value. Are you the author of the class you are using? Can you edit the class?

Answer (score 1):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($msg);
$prop = $reflection->getProperty("tag");
$prop->setAccessible(true);
$tag = $prop->getValue();
```

But this is little bit hack way, if you has ProtocolNode in your sorce then it is better to add getter "getTag", if ProtocolNode is some vendor lib class, then you can extend ProtocolNode to MyProtocolNode and add getter